# is it necessary to point my domain's dns servers to my hosting company?

Tags: dns, web-hosting

Here is something I had never thought about, although I've done it several times.

When you get web hosting, the hosting company always asks you to point your domain's DNS servers to them in order for the hosting to work. Once I do that, I go to the DNS management section and I notice they've setup the A and MX records in order for their servers to handle the web requests and the mail for my domain.

However I'm curious.

If I wanted to handle the DNS of my domain through my domain registar (or a third party DNS service), but still use a web hosting provider, would it be possible to just setup the A and MX records in my domain registar DNS interface to point to the web hosting company server ips? Or is it not possible without the webhosting company handling the DNS for my domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do, if you point an A record at the hosting company's server it should work just fine. Going through the hosting company just makes it easier to manage your subdomains.

Comment: got it, makes sense jli. can you provide any URL that somewhat backs the answer up? also, most web hostings today offer functionality to install wordpress or other web apps, that'd still work too just by having the A line, right?

Comment: @silverCORE Everything should work fine with just the A record. The DNS record is just a pointer from the domain name to an IP address, nothing more. I don't have a working example to show you, but in the past I have done just that and it has worked fine.